# How to wait until all data is downloaded in Firebase (Firestore) Storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am doing a light dashboard in Vue with Firestore and Storage. I am not a pro so I am stuck in something that should be easy. I have one function that should get all URLs based on filenames (that is how Storage works)

```
getImages: function(uid, images) {        
    images.forEach((filename) => {
        var ref = firebaseApp.storage().ref('images/' + uid + "/" + filename);
        ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {   
          this.finalImages.push(url)
          console.log(url);
        }).catch(function(error) {
          switch (error.code) {
            case 'storage/object_not_found':
              // File doesn't exist
              console.log('Object not found');
              break;

            case 'storage/unauthorized':
              // User doesn't have permission to access the object
              console.log('You do not have the right permissions');
              break;

            case 'storage/canceled':
              // User canceled the upload
              console.log('Canceled');
              break;

            case 'storage/unknown':
              // Unknown error occurred, inspect the server response
              console.log('Who knows...');
              break;
          }
        })
    })
  }
```

But URLs download after code finishes so I never see them. How can I stop everything and wait for URLs to appear in `finalImages` array and then continue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map each request to a promise then wait for all of the promises to complete:

```
getImages: function(uid, images) {        
  Promise.all(images.map((filename) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var ref = firebaseApp.storage().ref('images/' + uid + "/" + filename);
      ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
        resolve(url);
      }).catch(function(error) {
        // Uncomment this line to ignore errors.
        reject(error);
        switch (error.code) {
          case 'storage/object_not_found':
            // File doesn't exist
            console.log('Object not found');
            break;

          case 'storage/unauthorized':
            // User doesn't have permission to access the object
            console.log('You do not have the right permissions');
            break;

          case 'storage/canceled':
            // User canceled the upload
            console.log('Canceled');
            break;

          case 'storage/unknown':
            // Unknown error occurred, inspect the server response
            console.log('Who knows...');
            break;
        }
      })
    });
  })).then((finalImages) => {
    // all images.
  })
}
```